# how to allow my iframe content to go full screen, or a better alternative to iframe?

Tags: html, iframe, url-shortener

### Background

I have a domain http://www.example.com

I have some content at another ugly URL like http://www.othersite.com/blahblahblah/foo

The content however, is a nice interactive catalog / animation thingy (I'm not 100% sure if it runs on Flash or JavaScript or just plain HTML5).

I've got everything working just great with an `iframe`, except... the content has a button which enables it to go to Full Screen mode.

When I load the http://www.othersite.com/blahblahblah/foo page directly, Full Screen mode works fine.  When I load it in an `iframe`, the Full Screen mode button does nothing.

### Objective

All I'm really concerned with is hiding the original URL and replacing it with my much shorter / prettier URL, and hopefully maintaining the full screen functionality at the same time.  I also have admin access to the Apache server where http://www.example.com is, if that gives me any additional options.

### Questions

1. Is there a way I can make the Full Screen mode work in an `iframe`?
2. If not, is there a better alternative to `iframe`?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I just found there is a `allowFullScreen="true"` switch for the `iframe` tag!

Works in Chrome, but doesn't seem to work in Internet Explorer 11 :(